# How do i access a functions variables which is being called by a callback?

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, callback, telegram-bot

I want to be able to print the value of "Message_From_User" from the function. How can I do this?

I've tried using return, but it required me to call the function, like this E.G. start(), which I can not do.

The function is currently being called by a callback because that is the only way to make this code run. The code is using the [Python-telegram-bot](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) library.

I've provided a bot token so all you have to do to run this code is to install the python-telegram-bot library.

```
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters

updater = Updater(token='<MY-TOKEN>', use_context=True)#Please enter your token

dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
Message_From_User = "123"
def start(update, context):
    global Message_From_User
    Message_From_User = update.message.text # How do i access this var from outside the function


dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, start)) #Callback which requires 2 arguments

updater.start_polling()
print(Message_From_User)
```

EDIT: I want the variable "Message_From_User" to be accessible from anywhere, even from other files when I import the code.

Comment: Where do you want to print `Message_From_User`? It is a global variable and should be available anywhere in your program.

Comment: If you don't call the function, that code doesn't run and `update.message.text` isn't accessed. You can print `Message_From_User` whenever, but it won't have been updated.

Comment: Can you verify the callback runs when you expect it too?

Comment: @DYZ, I want it to be accessible from anywhere in the program as well as accessible from other files when I import it. Also thank you for commenting, I really appreciate it. :)

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I am running the code by using a callback.

Comment: @MartinKleiven, yes the call back runs correctly. Also thank you for helping. :)

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19585935/returning-values-from-callbacks-in-python? I tried running your code, but I'm not sure when to expect a value change. When does the callback run?

Comment: Your BOT token was in the question. I removed it, but it's still visible in the history. Consider renewing the token at @botFather to prevent other people abusing it!